# SQL GroupBy & Get Non Group rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

I've data as follows

| AreaId | AreaName | Module |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | Square |
| 2 | AAA | Circle |
| 3 | BBB | Square |
| 4 | CCC | Square |
| 5 | CCC | Circle |
| 6 | DDD | Circle |

I'm looking for some help in SQL to get the data as follows

| AreaName | SquareArea | CircleArea |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 | 2 |
| BBB | 3 | Null |
| CCC | 4 | 5 |
| DDD | Null | 6 |

I've tried with Distinct. But I'm unable to prepare the SQL for the data result that I'm looking for

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard pivot.

```
SELECT AreaName, SquareArea = [Square], CircleArea = [Circle]
  FROM dbo.YourTableName
  PIVOT (MAX(AreaID) FOR Module IN ([Square],[Circle])) AS p;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/slcmuvqy).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (AreaID INT IDENTITY, AreaName NVARCHAR(3), Module NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @table (AreaName, Module) VALUES
('AAA','Square'),('AAA','Circle'),('BBB','Square'),
('CCC','Square'),('CCC','Circle'),('DDD','Circle')
```

Example data is much easier to use when it's presented as a defined object.

```
SELECT AreaName, AVG(CASE WHEN Module = 'Square' THEN AreaID END) AS SquareArea, 
                 AVG(CASE WHEN Module = 'Circle' THEN AreaID END) AS CircleArea
  FROM @table t
 GROUP BY t.AreaName
```

You will need to decide which aggregation method you want to use though, MIN? MAX? AVG?